# manage.py test: error: argument -v/--verbosity: expected one argument

Tags: python, django

I'm learning testing.

I want to test a SignupForm I have, and for that I'm using the package `coverage`.

However, when running:

```
coverage run manage.py test shop/tests -v
```

I get:

```
$ coverage run manage.py test shop/tests -v
usage: manage.py test [-h] [--noinput] [--failfast] [--testrunner TESTRUNNER]
                      [-t TOP_LEVEL] [-p PATTERN] [-k] [-r] [--debug-mode]
                      [-d] [--parallel [N]] [--tag TAGS]
                      [--exclude-tag EXCLUDE_TAGS] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                      [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH]
                      [--traceback] [--no-color] [--force-color]
                      [test_label [test_label ...]]
manage.py test: error: argument -v/--verbosity: expected one argument
(stickers-gallito-app)
```

**shop/tests/test_forms.py:**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
from shop.forms import SignUpForm

#coverage run manage.py test shop/tests -v

class SignUpFormTest(TestCase):
    def test_signup_form(self):
        form_data = {'first_name': 'oma',
                     'last_name': 'gonza',
                     'username': 'omagonza',
                     'email': 'oma.gonzales@gmail.com',
                     'password1': 'caballo123',
                     'password2': 'caballo123'}
        form = SignUpForm(data=form_data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

**shop/forms.py:**

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': "Las contraseñas no coinciden.",
    }

    first_name = forms.CharField(label="Nombre", max_length=100, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Apellido', max_length=100, required=True)
    username = forms.CharField(label='Nombre de usuario', max_length=100, required=True,
                               error_messages={'invalid': "you custom error message"})
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Correo electrónico', max_length=60, required=True)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Contraseña', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirmar contraseña', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for fieldname in ['username', 'password1', 'password2']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1',
                  'password2')
```

**structure:**

```
|_shop
  |_migrations
  |_templates
  |_tests
    |___init__.py #empty file
    |_test_forms.py
```

Comment: Add a number from `0` to `3` after the `-v`.

Comment: @KlausD. which one? how to know the meanings?

Comment: Ok, it's about the verbosity (information) provided. I'm going with number 2 after the coverage command. Ty.